# Detecting when SKSpriteNode is completely below another SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

For a game I'm creating, an SKSpriteNode gradually makes its way down the user's screen. There's another SKSpriteNode (position is static) near the bottom of the screen, leaving only a little bit of space for the original SKSpriteNode to fit in. I need to detect when the first SKSpriteNode is COMPLETELY below the second SKSpriteNode, which I'm having a bit of trouble with. Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
if (pos.y > barPosY) //pos.y = 1st SKSpriteNode, barPosY = 2nd SKSpriteNode
{
    touchedTooEarly = true
}
```

For some reason, when the first SKSpriteNode goes just a little bit over the 2nd SKSpriteNode (not all the way), it still detects it as being completely over. Is there a coordinate space issue I'm missing?

Comment: you are not accounting for the heights of the sprite,  you need to make sure that `pos.y - pos.frame.height/2 > barPosY + bar.frame.height/2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The logic

A sprite `a` covers a sprite `b` if

1. `b.frame` is inside `a.frame`
2. `b.zPosition` is below `a.zPosition`

### The extension

Now let's build an extension

```
extension SKSpriteNode {
    func isCoveredBy(otherSprite: SKSpriteNode) -> Bool {
        let otherFrame = CGRect(
            origin: convertPoint(otherSprite.position, fromNode: otherSprite),
            size: otherSprite.frame.size
        )
        return zPosition < otherSprite.zPosition && CGRectContainsRect(frame, otherFrame)
    }
}
```

### Problem #1: transparency

This mechanism totally ignores transparency.

### Problem #2: same sprite

If you compare 2 sprites of the same type the function `CGRectContainsRect` will return true only when they are exactly aligned. Althoug you can solve this problem creating a smaller rectangle when you compare the sprites.